# Keep cell 100% height on slideToggle in grid

Tags: jquery, html, css

Click on `LEFT` - you'll see - it loses its 100% height. How can I keep `LEFT` always full height, regardless of whether `TOP` is visible or not.

```js
$('.left').on('click', function() {
  $('#top').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.top {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background: gold;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='top' id='top'>TOP</div>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `height:inherit` in your `left` css might solve your problem

```
.left {
  background: lightblue;
  height:inherit
}
```

```js
$('.left').on('click', function() {
  $('#top').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.top {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background: gold;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
  height:inherit
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='top' id='top'>TOP</div>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `height: 100vh;` to `.left in css`

```
.left {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.left').on('click', function() {
    $('#top').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.top {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background: gold;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='top' id='top'>TOP</div>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm... in that case inner content of `LEFT` will be outside of scroll area at the bottom, i.e. will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to accomplish that smoothly.

The first thing is that you need to understand that when you toggle something, it disappears from the DOM, meaning that the first element that will receive the grid-template-rows will be the left element. You want that to be 1fr.

The second is timing. Since the functions are non-blocking, it means they will run in parallel if you animate in one line and change the property on the next. If you attach them to the slideToggle instead, you will be able to postpone its execution to when the animation ends.
http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Hope that helps :)

```js
$('.left').on('click', function() {
  $('#top').slideToggle(( 800, function() {
    $('.parent').css('grid-template-rows', '1fr');
  }));
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.top {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background: gold;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='top' id='top'>TOP</div>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only work for the first click. After you click a second time the .parent div will remain with grid-template-rows: 1fr

Comment: You may add flags to toggle the right function and change the classes, but the main purpose was to help understand what really happens, and why does that behaviour appears other than just providing a solution that someone can copy/paste. I always love to learn more about why is something happening.